# Apache Spark nested iterations in Scala to generate stats RDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark, mapreduce, apache-spark-sql, rdd

I have an RDD made by rowkey = client_id, campaigns = a Json array of {campaign_id:campaign_name}

```
val clientsRDD = resultRDD.map(ClientRow.parseClientRow)
// change  RDD of ClientRow  objects to a DataFrame
val clientsDF = clientsRDD.toDF()
// Return the schema of this DataFrame
clientsDF.printSchema()
// print each line DataFrame
clientsDF.collect().foreach(println)
```

The output:

```
root
 |-- rowkey: string (nullable = true)
 |-- campaigns: string (nullable = true)

[1,[{"1000":"campaign1"},{"1001":"campaign2"}]]
[2,[{"1002":"campaign3"}]]
```

I have also an RDD full of records from HBase with all clients and campaigns data.

recordsRDD

```
rowkey                 type         body
client_id-campaign_id, record_type, record_text
```

My aim is to generate statistics for every client (considering all its campaigns) and for every single campaign, for example counting all client_id records, grouping by type and counting every single campaigns records, grouping them by type.

```
client1
records:100, login:20, actions:80

client1 campaign1  
records:70, login:16, actions:50

client1 campaign2
records:30, login:4, actions:30
```

In the end i want to write statistics.

What's the best approach for doing this in Spark with Scala?
Do i have to iterate clientsRDD (map ?), and for every row generate different RDDs mapping recordsRDD?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly you need to defined schema for campaigns field:
It means
You define schema with

```
val schema = StructType(Seq(StructField("rowkey", StringType, true),
StructField("campaigns", StructType(
  StructField("id", StringType, true) ::
    StructField("name", StringType, true) :: Nil
))
```

))

Then you can use `explode` method in campaigns field to make row flat.

```
val df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(clientsRDD, schema)
df.select(col("rowkey"), explode(col("campaigns")).as("campaign")).filter(col("campaign.id") === 1)
```